# How to transfer a binary file through serial?

Tags: serial-port, teraterm

I brought a new hardware (connected through USB as /dev/ttyUSB0).
I need to transfer a binary os.bin file through serial. The hardware has a inbuilt UART driver.

I downloaded putty & couldn't see any file transfer method in the options.

But I do see file transfer options in Teraterm, but many:
kermit, X,Y & ZMODEM, Quick Van and B-Plus.

Now, I don't know about any of the protocol mentioned above.

I expect the new hardware to have only UART driver. (at a specified baud rate 115200 8N1 as mentioned in the manual)

Now, how can I tranfer os.bin to HW? & 
Which option should I choose in Teraterm if I use Teraterm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an option in Teraterm under File->Send file... that can be used to send binary file over.

If you have a binary file just check the box "binary" in the option section of the sendFile Window before pressing "Open" with your specific file selected.

Some information about sendfile here: https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/macro/command/sendfile.html

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use sx and rx, busybox have rx

**ex: if you have a connection like putty to target on ttyUSB0**

on host:

```
$ sx filename < /dev/ttyUSB0 > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

on target (putty):

```
# rx filename
```

Comment: the correct is first rx on target and later sx on host

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plink` from `putty` package.

Also you can use `slattach` utility to establish p2p network connection to another device.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Teraterm `File` -> `Send file...` command will send the contents of the file, but you still need something running on the remote machine to receive it (otherwise it just dumps the contents of the file to the command line or whatever other command processor the remote machine is running).

Although I'm sure there are better and more sophisticated ways to do this, I sent a text file by opening an editor on the remote machine (I used `vi` but ymmv) and then executing the Teraterm `File` -> `Send file...` command, so the contents of the file were dumped into the editor.

The principle is the same for Kermit, Xmodem, etc., in that for any of these to work you need to be running the appropriate program on the receiver (e.g. Kermit) before initiating the send on Teraterm.